# Change the commit I'm branching from

Tags: git

When working on a feature branch, how can I get the latest code from the main develop branch?

I'd like to go from this:

```
{Master Branch}    A-B-C-G-H
{Feature branch}        \D-E-F
```

to this:

```
{Master Branch}A-B-C-G-H
{Feature branch}        \D-E-F
```

Where {A...H} are all commits.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `git-merge` the master branch into your feature branch.  This will get you everything that is in master into feature.

Check out info here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging

Answer (score 2):

You're asking to rewrite the history of the branch so that those commits start from a different point.
That will break any clones of your repo.

If you're sure you want to do that,

```
git rebase master
```

Comment: Break is a bit of a strong word. Nothing breaks. It just changes the lineage. This forces your team to adapt, which is no big deal for those good at git, but it's considered rude if done unannounced, and at companies where people aren't good with git, it makes people panic, and is considered 'against the rules.' Anyway, you should also note that `git rebase master` must be done while on the feature branch.